# How to keep hover after hover effect?

Tags: css

I have this hover effect http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMbEdq but problem is that after animation finishes, the hover disappear. I need that hover to stay. Any suggestion?

```
 <div class="hover15">
    <figure><img src="http://nxworld.net/codepen/css-image-hover-effects/pic03.jpg" /></figure>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use following Code :

```
transition-duration: 100s;
```

Use the following code where ever you want animation to hold or stay for sometime. And if you want it to loop or play @ click events kindly refer to **KeyFrames**.

Use like this :

```
@keyframes hover {
 0% {
   // normal styles
 }
 100% {
   // hover styles
 }
}

.class {
 animation-name: hover;
 animation-duration: 1ms;
 animation-fill-mode: backwards;
 animation-play-state: paused;      
 }

.class:active,
.class:focus,
.class:hover {
   //hover style you define
 }
```

Reference [click here to see the effect](http://codepen.io/morewry/full/GLjpK)

Comment: #none wait i'm updating my code that would let you at ease while implementing

Comment: Good answer, I upvote it, but I edited it removing some unneccesary things

Comment: Thanks Marcos for liking it. And you're correction would always be appreciated. Cheers :)